# Drupal Organic Groups: Automatically make all members group admins

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, access-control, organic-groups

I'm using Drupal 6 to build a web application which will be centered around small groups (using Organic Groups).
All the groups are invite only, and once a user is a member of the group I trust him to have full groups admin rights (e.g. invite other users).

Any ideas on how I can set all group members to be group admins by default.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is implementing the og hook on the operation 'user insert', and rewriting the record with is_admin = 1:

```
function supporttip_og($op, $gid, $uid, $args) {
  if($op == 'user insert') {
    $time = time();
    $subscription = array(
      'nid' => $gid,
      'uid' => $uid,
      'changed' => $time,
      'is_admin' => 1
    );
    drupal_write_record('og_uid', $subscription, array('nid', 'uid'));
  }
}
```